# Jquery Select Problem

Tags: jquery

**Jquery Code:**

```
$("[id$=mytable] tr").click(function() {

    alert($(this).html());

});
```

Html:

```
<table id="mytable">

    <tr>
      <td class="locked">1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="locked">a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>      
    </tr>      
  </table>
```

ı need only "td class='locked'" click return this

click: `<td class="locked">1</td>`

output:

```
<tr>
      <td class="locked">1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>      
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

**[I created a demo for you here](http://jsbin.com/isevo)**

```
$(function(){
  $('td.locked').click(function(){
   var html = $(this).parent().html();
   alert('<tr>' + html + '</tr>');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('table#mytable tr td.locked').click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().html());
});
```

Comment: @oraclee, if you're happy with the answer, could you please "accept" it?

Comment: don't just thank him (her?). Upvote Mailslut and accept the answer ;)

Comment: @Daren Thomas 10 minutes wait :S

Answer (score 0):

I originally had a solution much like the others here, that is, to bind the callback to the `td.locked`. I guess you really want to bind it to the `tr` and only output the `td.locked`, so here is my version:

```
$("#mytable tr").click(function() {

    alert($(this).find("td.locked").html());

});
```

Comment: Other way round, click (bind) to the TD, and output the contents of the TR